# Add object of certain size

Tags: dimensions

I am trying to add a cubed object of certain dimensions instead of the default cube. I have looked over the documentation and can't see a way to do this.

To clarify. I'm looking for a 3D program that acts like CAD in that if I want to add an object in SI units I can. Eg 10mm x 25mm x 12.5mm. Or I want to change an object created by someone else. Scale does me no good if I don't have reference to the current size and units, and I'm not sure why anyone would want or need to do all that work when the rest of the world understands units.

Comment: Once you've added the cube, use the operator panel to change its size. Next time you add one, it will have the same size.

Comment: Right click on add cube, view docs, follow first link [Adjust Last Operation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/undo_redo.html#adjust-last-operation)

Comment: If you want to change the New file so it has a different sized Cube, make the changes and File->Defaults->Save Startup File. Or you can use Python to create a cube of specific size.

Answer (score 3):

Use the operator size after you add a mesh in Blender 2.79

### Blender 2.79b

[image: 2.7]

Use the operator size after you add a mesh in Blender 2.79 in the *Add Cube* panel

### Blender 2.81

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In order to get a cube of certain dimensions, you create a cube, and, while in object mode, go over to the tool bar that comes up when you hit the "t" key.  Under the Item tab (in 2.79 it's under Transform), you will find dimension settings.  Be it known that when you change the dimensions, it also changes the scale of the object, so you will need to apply scale later.

In order to apply scale, you just need to hit ctrl-A and select from the drop-down "scale".

[image: cubedimensions]

Comment: oops... looks like this might not have been the answer your looking for.  If not, I can delete this answer.

Comment: my answer won't change your default cube.  Sounds like that was what you wanted.